# Pandas join record by matching on at least one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
id          phone       email
10352897        
10352897    10225967    
10352897                user@gmail.com
10352897    10225967    user@gmail.com
            10225967    
            10225967    user@gmail.com
                        user@gmail.com
23578910        
23578910    38256789    
23578910                user2@gmail.com
23578910    38256789    user2@gmail.com
            38256789    
            38256789    user2@gmail.com
                        user2@gmail.com
```

I would like that when it coincides in at least one of the three columns, the record joins and prioritizes the filled fields over the empty ones, in the end in this example I would expect the following output:

```
id          phone       email
10352897    10225967    user@gmail.com
23578910    38256789    user2@gmail.com
```

How would you go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) as follows

```
df_new = df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).reset_index()

[Out]:

         id     phone            email
0  10352897  10225967   user@gmail.com
1  23578910  38256789  user2@gmail.com
```